# MongoParseError: Invalid scheme

Tags: node.js, server, mern, mongodb-atlas, data-uri

I am working on connecting to a MongoDB Atlas database but continue to get this error:

```
MongoParseError: Invalid scheme, expected connection string to start with "mongodb://" or "mongodb+srv://"
```

I've tried hardcoding the username and password for ATLAS_URI in my .env file, as well as placing the environment variables within ATLAS_URI but continue to get the same error. Here is my .env file:
`ATLAS_URI = mongodb+srv://{DBUSER}:{DBPWD}@qac.mqn4ubr.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

and this is what I have stored in conn.mjs & loadEnvironment.mjs:

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

const connectionString = process.env.ATLAS_URI || ''
console.log(connectionString)
const client = new MongoClient(connectionString)

let conn
try {
    conn = await client.connect()
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
}

let db = conn.db('sample_training')


export default db
```

```
js
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()
```

I've been following this tutorial:[MERN tutorial: MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/languages/mern-stack-tutorial),

as well as this solution:[MongoParseError: Invalid scheme](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/unable-to-connect-db-because-of-throw-new-mongoparseerror-invalid-scheme-expected-connection-string-to-start-with-mongodb-or-mongodb-srv/176629/2) but nothing has fixed this.

The expectation is for the server to run on given port

Comment: have you tried adding a databse to the end like `.net/sample_training?retry...` ?  It's possible that the default is `admin` and atlas doesn't allow you to access db `admin`

Comment: Or ensure you don't have a space at the beginning of your URI . ..

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I was able to figure it out. For some reason it wasn't liking how I was storing my environment variables so I moved them and stored the .env in my gitignore